# Location for SSL certificates, how to secure them?

Tags: server, security, ssl, certificates

I have a nodeStatic app on an ubuntu server.

A domain links to the server.

Now I need to add SSL certificates:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/privatekey.pem').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/certificate.pem').toString()
};

var fileServer = new(nodeStatic.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(options, function(req, res) { 
  fileServer.serve(req, res);
}).listen(80);
```

The thing is they are not secure in the folder with the app, or am I wrong?

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

The app is in `var/www/myapp`

Anyone could open the contents of my certificates in the webbrowser with `example.com/ssl/privatekey.pem`

What is a good practise to serve the certificates and keep everything secure? Put them on the same level as index.js, or even further above? Is this secure?

Bonus question:

Kind of a general question, but the server is fresh, what shall I configure to keep everything secure? A good link on the topic would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make more sense to have something like nginx in front of your app, in this case. The setup would look like:

- Certificates in some place, not in your webroot, with the key only readable by root.
- Nginx configured to listen on ports 80 and 443, loading the certificate and key as root.
- Nginx will proxypass traffic to your node app listening on some other port (say 127.0.0.1:8080), which itself will run as a non-root user.

This way, the node app:

1. never sees the certificate key
2. can never serve it even if requested to, since the key is readable only by root
3. and so even if an attacker managed to access an arbitrary file or get shell access, they won't be able to access the key without getting a privilege escalation on top.

(As a bonus, you can then use certbot to get Let's Encrypt certificates automatically, and it will configure nginx to use them for you.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer

Answer (score -1):

1. Add middleware at that endpoint or Redirect to the other endpoint
2. Stop google indexing of that endpoint using a robot meta tag
3. Use Encryption and Decryption